# HP UFT recording with Oracle forms

Tags: automation, automated-tests, hp-uft

No script is generated on **HP UFT** when recording on an **Oracle forms 11 g** application.
I have a list item (drop down list) inside a canvas, and I'm trying to record a script to cover the drop down list changes.

I tried the *default*, *analogue*, *low level* and *insight* recording without success. Same behavior when creating a checkpoint, nothing is generated.(seems like the event is not captured by UFT)

UFT is able to record all other components changes successfully, the failure is only with the drop down.

This behavior produces failure in the Run phase and is blocking .
is there any turn around ? or any solution for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue while recording for that drop down object. Can you spy it?
If you can spy on the problematic object and check the documentation of that object in UFT- You can find the methods required to select the value from that drop down object.